# Why am I getting this 'number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length' error?

Tags: r, matrix, simulation

I have been trying to debug this code and I can't see where the error is coming from. I am trying to substitute the values of a beta distribution into a matrix along. The format I want to get it in is that I have the simulation number in the 1st column and then the different data points that have been simulated in the subsequent columns.

I have checked and it's been mentioned that I might be returning something that is a vector instead of a single number but I'm pretty sure that the output of rbeta is just a single value so why is it not letting me place this value into the matrix?

Thanks a bunch.

```
occ_simulation <- function(nyears, lambda, alpha, beta){
  
  data_matrix <- matrix(, nrow = nyears, ncol = 6)
  
  for (z in 1:nyears){
    data_matrix[z][1] <- z
  }
  
  for (yr in 1:nyears){
    
    poisson_sim = rpois(1, lambda)
    
    for (number_of_events in poisson_sim){
      print(number_of_events)
      
      if (number_of_events == 1){
        
        occ_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
                # data_matrix[yr][2] <- occ_sim
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 2){
        
          for (i in 2:3){
            
            occ_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
            # data_matrix[yr][i] <- occ_sim
            
          }
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 3){
          
          for (i in 2:4){
            
            occ_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
            # data_matrix[yr][i] <- occ_sim
        
          }
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 4){
        
          for (i in 2:5){
            
            occ_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
            data_matrix[yr][i] <- occ_sim
        
          }
          
      } else{
        
          for (i in 2:6){
            
            occ_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
            data_matrix[yr][i] <- occ_sim
        }
    
      }
      
    } 

  
  }
  print(data_matrix)
}

manual = occ_simulation(2, 10, 2, 20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

```
occ_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
data_matrix[yr][i] <- occ_sim
```

The `yr` variable loops over `1:nyears` and within that loop, there is a loop for `i` that goes from `2` to `6`.  So, let's say for the first year, you have `data_matrix[yr]` is a vector of length 1 and going through the loop when `i=2` the code `data_matrix[yr][i]` is trying to get the second element of a vector of length 1, which produces the error.

---

**EDIT** Answered comment

You could fix the function, if I understand what you're trying to do, by using `data_matrix[yr, i]` instead of `data_matrix[yr][i]`.  You could also  do `data_matrix[yr,][i]`, though this is a bit less clear.  Here is the code and result:

```
occ_simulation <- function(nyears, lambda, alpha, beta){
  
  data_matrix <- matrix(, nrow = nyears, ncol = 6)
  
  for (z in 1:nyears){
    data_matrix[z, 1] <- z
  }
  
  for (yr in 1:nyears){
    
    poisson_sim = rpois(1, lambda)
    
    for (number_of_events in poisson_sim){
      print(number_of_events)
      
      if (number_of_events == 1){
        
        occ_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
        data_matrix[yr, 2] <- occ_sim
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 2){
        
        for (i in 2:3){
          
          occ_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
          data_matrix[yr, i] <- occ_sim
          
        }
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 3){
        
        for (i in 2:4){
          
          occ_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
          data_matrix[yr, i] <- occ_sim
          
        }
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 4){
        
        for (i in 2:5){
          
          occ_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
          data_matrix[yr, i] <- occ_sim
          
        }
        
      } else{
        
        for (i in 2:6){
          
          occ_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
          data_matrix[yr, i] <- occ_sim
        }
        
      }
      
    } 
    
    
  }
  data_matrix
}

manual = occ_simulation(2, 10, 2, 20)
manual
#      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      [,5]        [,6]
# [1,]    1 0.05848754 0.04926032 0.03998070 0.1067415 0.006234281
# [2,]    2 0.09572200 0.02727308 0.01144517 0.0799155 0.066248752
```

Comment: I get the issue that is being caused now. My idea was to try and reference the place where I want the value of occ to be put into the matrix. So how would I go about defining that I was the result of occ_sim to be put into the matrix element [yr][i]?

Comment: @NeelPatel I added an edit to the answer to resolve your question.

Comment: That's awesome, I definitely see what I was doing wrong now. I had no clue that a comma was needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: @NeelPatel Happy to help.  When you used `data_matrix[yr]` it returns a single value.  When you do `data_matrix[yr, ]` it is returning all of the columns for the `yr` row. When you do `data_matrix[yr,i]` it is referring to the ith column value in the `yr` row.

Comment: Ah that definitely helps with something later I have planned for this code as well. This has been bugging me for a while. Thank you so much. Python does it a bit differently, so I can get confused between the 2 notations sometimes.